# Jq mouseleave to remove background hover, prevents normal css hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got this navbar with a dropdown ul on it.

```
<ul class="topbar-nav">
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="services.php" class="fixed_hover">Services</a>
   <ul class="drop_down">
      <li><a href="#">lorem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">lorem</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I'll just put the css for the hovered state of the "topbar-nav li"

```
ul.topbar-nav a.selected, ul.topbar-nav a:hover{
    color:#000;
    background:url(img/nav_hove.png) no-repeat;
    margin:0;
    padding-top:2px;
    }
```

And here is the jq code to slideDown/up the dropdownmenu. (I got this code from a tutorial )

```
function mainmenu(){
$(" .topbar-nav ul ").css({display: "none"});
$(" .topbar-nav li ").hover(function(){
    $(this)
      .find('ul:first:hidden')
      .css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"})
      .slideDown(400);

    },function(){
        $(this)
          .find('ul:first')
          .slideUp(400);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    mainmenu();
});
```

Now, everything is perfect, but i want the css hover rule (which assign the nav_hove.png background to the ul.topbar-nav li) to be present when you are hovering over the dropdown menu items, i couldn't do it with css, so i decided to try it by myself on jquery, and it worked except that when i hover again on the "services" tab no background will come to place. Here is my messy code for that:

```
$(function fixed_hover(){
   $("ul.drop_down li").hover(function fixed_hover(){
            $(".fixed_hover").css('background', 'url(img/nav_hove.png) no-repeat');
        }
    );
});
$(function fixed_hover2(){
      $("ul.drop_down li").mouseleave(function fixed_hover2(){
            $(".fixed_hover").css('background', 'none');
        }
    );
});
```

I'll appreciate any kind of help, and i'll thank you guys in advance for just reading this much. If you need more info about it, just let me know, though i hope i made myself clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second function, try setting the property to a blank value instead of none, like so:

```
$(".fixed_hover").css('background', '');
```

Otherwise, you're already using a class for selected, so why not just add and remove that?

```
$(function fixed_hover(){
   $("ul.drop_down li").hover(function fixed_hover(){
            $(".fixed_hover").addClass('selected');
        }
    );
});
$(function fixed_hover2(){
      $("ul.drop_down li").mouseleave(function fixed_hover2(){
            $(".fixed_hover").removeClass('selected');
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Flawless, both of your answers worked for me, you made my day crhistian, thanks for your help. Btw is there a way to add more than one css parameter on the css(), lets say add a padding in-there. Well no need to answer that one  ;). Thanks again

Comment: No worries :). Yeah it's pretty easy to do that, simply go like this: `.css({'left': 0, 'opacity': 0.5})` etc

Answer (score 1):

Try adding class on your element like this:

But be sure to CREATE that class in your CSS...

```
   $('.myDiv').hover(function(){
   $(this).addClass('active')


   },function(){
   $('.myDiv').removeClass('active')
   });
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me, my Dreamweaver tells me about a syntax error on your code. I created the class, but i not used to jq codes so I'm not sure if it was my fault of the code is buggy. In any case, I really appreciate your help, have a nice day. ;)